# How to handle conditionals in a styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am adding theme support for my app with styled components and ThemeProvider. The component in question already had a conditional to display style based on prop. When I introduce the theme I can't get the styles I need on the border property. They're just ignored. If replace them with a hex value I can see a border.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 130px !important;
  opacity: ${({ isDragging }) => (isDragging ? 0.25 : 1)};
  border: ${({ isSelected }) =>
    isSelected
      ? `1px solid ${props => props.theme.CYAN}`
      : `1px solid ${props => new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)}`};
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px !important;
  margin: 4px !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: ${({ isSelected }) =>
    isSelected
      ? props => new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)
      : props => props.theme.DARK} !important;

  & :hover {
    border-color: ${props => props.theme.CYAN};
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

<Wrapper
        isDragging={isDragging}
        isSelected={isSelected}
        onClick={onClick}
        className="daily-item"
      >


export const CLASSIC_THEME = {
  DARK: '#282a2b',
  LIGHT: 'white',
  CYAN: '#2edaf4',
  GREEN: '#26fba3',
  PURPLE: '#6f24bd',
  PINK: '#dd2df4',
  LIGHT_PURPLE: '#6d47f6',
  RED: '#f42d61',
  GREY: '#a6a6a6',
};

export const PRIMARY_THEME = {
  DARK: '#1f2630',
  LIGHT: '#EEEEFF',
  CYAN: '#BFC0C0',
  GREEN: '#9FB4C7',
  PURPLE: '#6f24bd',
  PINK: '#C89047',
  LIGHT_PURPLE: '#6d47f6',
  RED: '#f42d61',
  GREY: '#a6a6a6',
};
```

I'm aware these keys are not accurately describing the hex value :) I'm gonna get to that

Comment: can you share the ThemeProvider code?

Comment: I added the ThemeProvider

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant can you share the actual theme objects, what CLASSIC_THEME for example refers too. Are you sure it has a property called CYAN in there?

Comment: ok, updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a tagged template literal on the styled div, that's how you get a reference to props. In your approach however I notice you deconstruct the isSelected property out of props and then attempt to use props by adding another arrow function inside, which is not part of the tagged template literal. I'm guessing that's why it does not work. Try the following:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 130px !important;
  opacity: ${({ isDragging }) => (isDragging ? 0.25 : 1)};
  border: ${props =>
    props.isSelected
      ? `1px solid ${props.theme.CYAN}`
      : `1px solid ${new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)}`};
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px !important;
  margin: 4px !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: ${props =>
    props.isSelected
      ? new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)
      : props.theme.DARK} !important;

  & :hover {
    border-color: ${props => props.theme.CYAN};
    box-shadow: none;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

what does `props.theme.CYAN` look like? As you said, if you replace it with a HEX it works, which leads me to believe the issue may not be the conditional but `new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)`.

Comment: well that pattern works everywhere else that I use it, as long as it's not part of a conditional like this. This is what I get when I log it ``` ƒ (props) {
  return props.theme.CYAN;
}```

Comment: To be clear, that's what I get in components that work correctly, and this component I'm asking about

Comment: Can you confirm that ` new Color` is an external library? (It might just be something I am not familiar with in JS). That being said, the value of `props.theme.CYAN` may not be compatible with that library. can you console log the value? and let us know what it is? 

 : `1px solid ${props =>console.log('color', props.theme.CYAN) || new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)}`};

Comment: Color is an external library. I have removed `new Color(...` and replaced with `props => props.theme.CYAN` and have the same result. I don't think that is the problem :(

Comment: the Issue may be the object you are passing into it as etarhan said above. `props.theme.CYAN` may not be a valid colour value. Can you log `props.theme` out so we know the data we are working with?

Comment: It's definitely there. code like this `props => new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)` and this `props => props.theme.CYAN` is working as expect all over the app. It just doesn't work in the context of conditional like this

Comment: Can you 100% confirm its there with a console.log? It may be silly, but removing any doubt in situations like this will lead to an answer.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how to log `props.theme` effectively. It just returns:  `ƒ (props) { return props.theme; }`

Comment: replace


`1px solid ${props => new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)}`


with 

`1px solid ${props => console.log('props.theme.CYAN', props.theme.CYAN) ||  new Color(props.theme.CYAN).alpha(0.25)}`